# Telegram bot parse mode HTML does not work in PHP

Tags: php-telegram-bot

I am writing a telegram bot with php, and it is intended to send a news website to the user. The website has HTML codes inside with several attributes, e.g. <p> with many styles defined in line. I would like to send this code to telegram via the following command

```
file_get_contents($path."/sendmessage?chat_id=CHAT_ID&text=HTML_CODE&parse_mode=html);
```

$path is a variable including the telegram API url with my bot's token. I have tried this, and this does not work. Simply, the message does not appear. I have tried that the message would be sent if instead of the HTML_CODE there was another simple text, or if I had removed the parse_mode=html.

My question is as follows: is there a simple way to twist this code to be able to send the HTML code directly to telegram?